# Get route distance in Google My Maps

Tags: google-my-maps

Creating a map in Google My Maps by adding a route. Route drawing is fine, but how to get the distance between points?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- click on 3-dots
- select **Step-by-step directions**

[image]

Comment: "Step by Step Directions" does not appear in the "three dots" menu.  Only "Delete" and "Rename".  How do I get the "Step by Step" option to appear?

Comment: @garyp https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGwKW.png

Comment: That option did not appear when I first entered the route.    I came back six hours later, and it was there.  Go figure.   And thanks.

Comment: @user0 thank you for the answer. I wanted to add that this is a really bad user experience. I had to google to find your answer in a "map application".